# Angular 2 dynamically generated form group

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, formbuilder

I am trying to dynamically generate a FormBuilder group and I am stuck with the generated group object. I have the following component which is for a single .html input field.

```
import { Component, onInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    job: any;

    constructor(
        public formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.job = {
            number: 'J001'
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        const jobGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
        for (const key in this.job) {
            if (this.job.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const control: FormControl = new FormControl(this.job[key], Validators.required);
                jobGroup.addControl(this.job[key], control);
            }
        }

        this.jobForm = this.formBuilder.group(jobGroup);
    }
}
```

When the application loads, I get the following error in the console.

```
Error: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:12:50 caused by: Cannot find control with name: 'number'
```

The `home.component.html` is as follows.

```
<form [formGroup]="jobForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="number">Job Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="number" id="number">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Save Record</button>
</form>
```

I am hoping that this is something obvious that I have missed.

Comment: have you tried adding a `name` attribute to your input field?

Comment: Yep, same problem..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you have two mistakes here:

1) `this.obj[key]` should be key

2) you don't need to call `formBuilder.group` with parameter `FormGroup`

```
const jobGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
for (const key in this.job) {
  if (this.job.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const control: FormControl = new FormControl(this.job[key], Validators.required);
    jobGroup.addControl(key, control); // instead of this.obj[key]
  }
}

this.jobForm = jobGroup; // jibGroup is already formGroup
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/b4jbvRXrVGOfLINXiFlt?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure? I will do a plunker

Comment: That would be awesome!

Comment: You can check it here https://plnkr.co/edit/b4jbvRXrVGOfLINXiFlt?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. Annoyingly I am getting the job from a promise in the constructor and this is what appears to be causing the issue.

Comment: If you have dynamic forms then you should use `ngFor` for your controls as described here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Comment: Or use ngIf like `*ngIf="jobForm.contains('number')"` for static html

Comment: See also this example https://plnkr.co/edit/DCyvBK87j2VeqAw8XjSZ?p=preview where i am simulating async call

Comment: Your awesome!! Thanks for the help, have a great day :-)

Comment: What about the setTimeout on the this.job = {} i.e. simulate a promise?

Comment: Yes it just update form in the next tick as if you call http requestl

Comment: Could you do a plunk? :-)

Comment: Here is new plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/huF8wwoBcX0HGhmxw2HR?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui that doesn't solve how you pass the correct value to `formControlName` in the Dom

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControlName-directive.html) for formControlName

You need to declare formGroup (you've done it), and the controls as well (this part is missing).

```
const jobGroup = new FormGroup({
    // declare number here
    number: new FormControl()
});
```

Comment: Thank you.. although I am still getting the error with the following code.

Comment: `const group = {}

    for (const key in this.job) {
      if (this.job.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        group[key] = new FormControl(this.job[key]);
      }
    }

    this.jobForm = new FormGroup(group);`